# Custom checkout billing field data from Woocommerce isn't showing on admin order page and order email

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce

UPDATE:
I used the following code [from here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66934676/woocommerce-function-to-display-this-custom-field-value-on-the-order-edit-page) and it is fixed. The custom billing field is showing up in the backend and e-mails. Seemed like I needed to save the data to meta. Strange this isn't described on woocommerce's own documentation. Hope some else benefits from it too.

I've added some custom date fields to my checkout page. They are showing and I can input dates. But the input isn't showing in my admin order page or in de emails. I've searched some topics, but can't figure it out. I've followed [this instruction](https://woocommerce.com/document/tutorial-customising-checkout-fields-using-actions-and-filters/) under 'Adding Custom Shipping And Billing Fields'. I only see the label at the oder edit page and not the value. What is wrong here?

I only tried it with de 'date_from' field for testing purpose. 'date_till' also needs to be shown.

Code I got:

```
// Hook in
add_filter( 'woocommerce_checkout_fields' , 'custom_new_checkout_fields_date_from' );

// Our hooked in function – $fields is passed via the filter!
function custom_new_checkout_fields_date_from( $newDateFrom ) {
     $newDateFrom['billing']['date_from'] = array(
         'type'     => 'date',
        'label'     => __('Datum huur vanaf', 'woocommerce'),
    'placeholder'   => _x('Datum huur vanaf', 'placeholder', 'woocommerce'),
    'required'  => true,
    'class'     => array('form-row-wide'),
    'clear'     => true
     );

     return $newDateFrom;
}

// Datum tot veld
// Hook in
add_filter( 'woocommerce_checkout_fields' , 'custom_new_checkout_fields_date_till' );

// Our hooked in function – $fields is passed via the filter!
function custom_new_checkout_fields_date_till( $newDateTill ) {
     $newDateTill['billing']['date_till'] = array(
         'type'     => 'date',
        'label'     => __('Datum huur tot', 'woocommerce'),
    'placeholder'   => _x('Datum huur tot', 'placeholder', 'woocommerce'),
    'required'  => true,
    'class'     => array('form-row-wide'),
    'clear'     => true
     );

     return $newDateTill;
}

/**
 * Display field value on the order edit page
 */

add_action( 'woocommerce_admin_order_data_after_shipping_address', 'my_custom_checkout_field_display_admin_order_meta', 10, 1 );

function my_custom_checkout_field_display_admin_order_meta($order){
    echo '<p><strong>'.__('Datum huur van').':</strong> ' . get_post_meta( $order->get_id(), '_date_from', true ) . '</p>';
}

/**
 * Add a custom field (in an order) to the emails
 */
add_filter( 'woocommerce_email_order_meta_fields', 'custom_woocommerce_email_order_meta_fields', 10, 3 );

function custom_woocommerce_email_order_meta_fields( $keys, $sent_to_admin, $order ) {
    $keys['_date_from'] = array(
        'label' => __( 'Datum huur vanaf' ),
        'value' => get_post_meta( $order->id, '_date_from', true ),
    );
    return $keys;
}
```